# Distance Matrix (plugin) - QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have two points in OSGB 1936 (EPSG 27700):

A: 308188.48 608846.16

B: 308288.48 608846.16

Distance Matrix produces a result between A and B which is not exactly 100m (100.03935792736038 to be precise!). Why is that?

Comment: 4cm in 100m is almost certainly better than the measurement error in each point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have your **project ellipsoid measurement** set to the default `WGS 84` which gives the extra measurement. If you set it to `None / Planimetric`, you should get the exact value `100`.

You can set this from the menubar:

```
Project > Properties > General > Measurements
```

[image: project ellipsoid measurement]

Comment: Thanks Joseph, that solved the issue....this article provided some additional insight https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/coordinate-systems.html.

Comment: @hoopertr0n you should accept the answer if it solved your question.